# Creating an Expression that returns an object

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I have this method:

```
public R TranslateExpression<R>(Expression exp)
       where R : DbRequest
{
           //...
}
```

In another class I have the following method:

```
public void Persist(E entity)
{
     Expression expr = Expression.Return(entity); //Does not compile, but I'm looking for something like this

     PersistRequest request = TranslateExpression<PersistRequest>(expr);
}
```

How can I create an `Expression` that simply returns an instance?

Something like this: `() => { return entity; }`.

Comment: You can assign a lambda directly to a Expression variable.

Comment: @NickBailey no, you can't assign directly to `Expression` since it's not a delegate type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `Expression<Func<E>>` and then use a lambda expression to return your entity once the expression is invoked.

```
public void Persist<E>(E entity)
{
    Expression<Func<E>> expr = () => entity;    
    PersistRequest request = TranslateExpression<PersistRequest>(expr);
}

public R TranslateExpression<R>(Expression exp)
       where R : DbRequest
{
}
```

However, your `TranslateExpression` method is not particularly useful at this point since you've lost the power of your expression.  Unless you're doing something special inside of `TranslateExpression`, it might be better suited to something like the following signature:

```
public R TranslateExpression<R, E>(Expression<Func<E>> exp)
       where R : DbRequest
{
}
```

Comment: Just how I wanted the code to look like... beautiful!